# How to show the attribute table inside the dialogue of a custom plugin with QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

[image]

I need to create a custom table attribute inside a plugin where I can choose which layer I need to open and add new custom buttons to this custom table attribute

To become like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`QgsAttributeTableView`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableView.html) and [`QgsAttributeTableModel`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableModel.html) classes. These are used by QGIS to display the attribute table.

I've put together a small example script which shows the attribute table of a vector layer in a small custom dialog.
Instead of the label you can insert any desired other elements into the layout.

```py
class MyWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, canvas, layer):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel('Custom Widget')
        layout.addWidget(label)
        
        self.tableView = QgsAttributeTableView(self)
        self.layerCache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, layer.featureCount())
        self.tableModel = QgsAttributeTableModel(self.layerCache)
        self.tableModel.loadLayer()

        self.tableFilterModel = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(canvas, self.tableModel, parent=self.tableModel)
        self.tableFilterModel.setFilterMode(QgsAttributeTableFilterModel.ShowAll)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.tableFilterModel)
            
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
layer = iface.activeLayer()
dlg = MyWindow(iface.mainWindow(), iface.mapCanvas(), layer)
dlg.show()
```

[image: attr-table]

Comment: Thanks for your answear , what I want is to replicate the , table attribute and all the actions above the table attribute like the edit mode , save ...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem possible to me. QGIS creates all the actions above the attribute table in [`QgsAttributeTableDialog`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsattributetabledialog.cpp) class, which is **not** exposed through the python API. So I guess your only option would be to recreate those actions in python based on the original source file