# How to populate QTableView/QTableWidget with attribute table of a layer using PyQIS?

Tags: pyqgis-3, plugins, pyqt5

I am developing a a plugin in QGIS. I want to add attribute table of a vector layer as data model in QTableView. I am using following lines of code but it is adding empty column.

```
    vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(select_op, 10000)     
    attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)
    attribute_table_model.loadLayer()
    self.dlg.tableView.setModel(attribute_table_model)
```

How to get full attribute table displayed in QTableView/QTableWidget?

Comment: `QgsAttributeTableView.setModel()` does not receive a parameter of type `QgsAttributeTableModel` but a `QgsAttributeTableFilterModel` instead, where you can set a filter to show all features. Look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425009/how-to-show-the-attribute-table-inside-the-dialogue-of-a-custom-plugin-with-qgis/425042

Comment: That one gives the same output of empty columns.@CodeBard

Comment: Did you try the exact same code from the answer I linked? Because that clearly works for me. You may need to set all the objects as instance variables instead of local variables, so `self.attribute_table_model =` instead of `attribute_table_model =` etc.